# Can't boot to the original windows 8.1

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

After purchasing an SSD, I decided to install Windows 8.1 on it. I originally had Windows 8.1 on my Western Digital Hard drive. But now, I cannot boot to it and there is no option to select an operating system, it basically automatically goes to the Windows installed on the SSD.

Here are steps which I took to resolve the issue and nothing happened:

- I changed the boot sequence in BIOS to my original hard drive, but Windows does not boot from that drive
- I went to System Properties > Advanced > Startup and Recovery > Default Operating System but there is only one option to select from / time to display list of operating system is also checked
- I went to System Configuration > Boot and I can not see my Drive D (original Windows 8.1 installation) there is only one option (Windows 8.1 on Drive C)

I did not erase anything from Drive D (which I originally had windows 8.1) and I can access the drive folder but I cannot boot a Windows from it.

I had windows 7 and windows 8 before and there was an option to select an operating system, but that option doesnt exist if you have two windows 8.1 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

sry for my bad english.... but try this:
enter on windows setup and write this on console: Bootrec /RebuildBcd *press enter*
                                                  Bootrec /FixBoot *press enter*
                                                  Bootrec /FixMbr *press enter*
                                                  exit and restart....

Comment: thanks but I have already tried that too, not working

Comment: did you have installed windows by usb pen drive or cd?

Comment: I installed using a USB

Comment: i had the same problem an i just can boot it with inserted pen

Comment: use USB to boot? or to fix the boot?

Comment: use usb to boot, but boot with hdd on boot options

Comment: Its not clear the reason you think the MBR is broken.  Please provide clarity.